# Proving the existence of a continuous increasing function.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\left( {X,\mathcal{A},\,\mu } \right)$ be a finite measure space and suppose $f$ is a non-negative, measurable function that is finite at each point of $X$, but not necessarily intergrable. Prove that there exists a continuous increasing function $g:\left[ {0,\infty } \right) \to \left[ {0,\infty } \right)$ such that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } g\left( x \right) = \infty $ and $g \circ f$ is integrable.

I am totally clueless about how to proceed with this. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result for $\mathrm{ess}\sup f(X)<\infty$ is trivial, so we assume that $\mathrm{ess}\sup f(X)=\infty$. Since your $\mu$ is finite, you can just divide your $X$ into $X=\cup A_i$, $A_i=\{x\in X:k_i\leq f(x)< k_{i+1}\}$, such that $\mu(A_i)>3\mu(A_{i+1})>0$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Now first define $\hat{g}(y)=\frac{1}{2^i\mu(A_i)}$ for $y\in [k_i,k_{i+1})$. Then $\hat{g}$ is increasing, since $\frac{1}{2^i\mu(A_i)}<\frac{1}{2^{i+1}\mu(A_{i+1})}$ by the previous condition. In particular, $\frac{1}{2^i\mu(A_i)}>\frac{3^{i-1}}{2^i\mu(A_1)}\rightarrow\infty$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$, so $\hat{g}\rightarrow\infty$. We also know that $\int \hat{g}\circ fd\mu=\sum\frac{1}{2^i}<\infty$. Now to get a continuous $g$, you can just combine your step function $\hat{g}$ near all non continuity point by a line which doesn't change the integral. Then the $g$ is your sought.

---

There is still a little mistake at step 2, since I can not controll the distribution the values of $f$, so a changing by a line will also give a change to the integral. To fix this, we can use dominating convergence theorem: for the interval $[k_1,k_3]$, let $g_n$ be the continuous function which is combined by a line near the discontinuity of $[k_1,k_3]$, and the line converging to the line which is penparticular to the discontinuity. Then $\int_{A_1\cup A_2}g_n\circ f$ should converge to $\int_{A_1\cup A_2}\hat{g}\circ f$ due to dominating convergence theorem. We find a $n$ such that the gap is $\frac{1}{2}$. Then do it for the $i$-th discontinuity with a gap $(\frac{1}{2})^i$. At the end, the modificated function is our sought $g$.

Comment: How do you construct the $A_i$? For $\mu(A_i) > 3\mu(A_{i + 1})$ you need $k_{i + 1}$ to be close to $k_i$. But then it might happen that $k_i$ doesn't go to infinity.

Comment: @Dominik No, $k_{i+1}$ doesn't need to be close to $k_i$, for instanse, $\mu(A_1)>\frac{3}{4}\mu(X)$, but then you can take a larger $k_{2}$ in $A_1$ as you like. Then do the same for the rest.

Comment: Enlarging $k_{i + 1}$ will increase the measure of $A_{i + 1}$; You can't conclude that you keep the condition $3\mu(A_{i + 1}) < \mu(A_i)$.

Comment: @Dominik $k_{i+1}$ is in $A_i$. By the way, let me explain how I did: First, $\mu(A_1)>\frac{3}{4}\mu(X)$, then whatever $k_3$ you take, you always have $\mu(A_1)>3\mu(A_2)$. Do this induktive for the rest.

Comment: Why should this inductive step work? Try writing down an exact proof, then you should see that there are some flaws in your argumentation.

Comment: @Dominik let $B_i:=\{x:i\leq f(x)<i+1\}$. Then $\sum\mu(B_i)=\mu(X)<\infty$. Then we know there exists some $j$  such that $\sum_{i=1}^j\mu(B_i)>\frac{3}{4}\mu(X)$. Then define $A_1=\cup_{i=1}^j B_i$. Do the same for the rest set $\sum_{i=j+1}^\infty B_i$ to get $A_2,A_3,...$, I dont really see there is a problem. If you find a mistake, pls tell me.

Comment: Ok, I think now I understand your reasoning. You need to take $A_{i + 1}$ so large that $\mu(A_{i + 1}) > \frac{3}{4} \mu(X\setminus(A_1 \cup \ldots \cup A_i))$.

Comment: @Dominik yes exactly.